# Seeking guide for proper MySql "IF" method

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I need to grab data on specific column values, but also include items `IF` they have `inventory` enabled and `stock` is greater than 0.

The following is just a concept query to give a visual of my intent. Of course it doesn't work.

```
SELECT id, name, image, price
FROM shop
WHERE published = 1
AND price > 2
  /*concept clause here*/
    IF(inventory = 1 AND stock > 0, include, ignore)
  /*end concept*/
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 30
```

#### Table Structure

```
shop
__________________________________________
|id|name  |image   |price|inventory|stock|
------------------------------------------
|4 |widget|pic.jpg |6    |1        |12   |
------------------------------------------
|5 |bolt  |bolt.jpg|7    |0        |0    |
------------------------------------------
|6 |trowel|trow.jpg|12   |1        |0    |
__________________________________________
```

#### Desired Result

Array

```
[
    ['id'=>4,'name'=>'widget','image'=>'pic.jpg','price'=>6],
    ['id'=>5,'name'=>'bolt','image'=>'bolt.jpg','price'=>7]
]
```

The row with `inventory` enabled but `stock` value 0, will **not** be in the array.

**How can I achieve results based on this condition?**

---

#### Working but "dirty" solution

I've run the similar query twice, then merge the arrays

**Get items without inventory enabled**

```
SELECT id, name, image, price
FROM shop
WHERE published = 1
AND price > 2
AND inventory = 0 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 30
```

**Get items with inventory enabled and has stock**

```
SELECT id, name, image, price
FROM shop
WHERE published = 1
AND price > 2
AND inventory = 1 
AND stock > 0 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 30
```

**Merge arrays**

```
$merged = array_merge($withoutInventory, $withInventory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data and expected result would help clarify. I think you need to bracket your column selects and and OR them

```
SELECT id, name, image, price
FROM shop
WHERE (published = 1 AND price > 2) OR
      (inventory = 1 AND stock > 0)
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: I had attempted the method you present before, but I got `null` results. I edited the question to show table structure and desired result.

Comment: There is no column `published` in your table?